# Adding Crystal Report Installer to my Windows App Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, windows-installer, installation, detect

I am developing an App that uses Crystal Report. Now, it maybe the case that the Target machine doesn't have Crystal Report installed.

I understand that Crystal Report up to a certain version can be downloaded and used.
Now, I want to ensure that when the Setup Project for the App runs, it will detect if Crystal Report( or any dependency for that matter) is installed and have them installed either by showing a link or bundling the setup for Crystal Report with the Application Setup MSI file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done through prerequisites handled by an EXE bootstrapper. The bootstrapper usually performs predefined searches to determine if the prerequisite is required or not and also handles its installation.

If your setup authoring tool doesn't support prerequisites, you can try this:

- in your MSI create searches which determine if Crystal Reports is installed or not
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367579(VS.85).aspx
- create a custom action which launches the Crystal Reports installer
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368062(VS.85).aspx
- condition this custom action with the search properties

Since the Crystal Reports installer is also MSI-based, this custom action should be scheduled in InstallUISequence or after InstallExecuteSequence -> InstallFinalize as asynchronous.